# Error. Recording shinyapps.io apps is not supported

Tags: shiny, rstudio, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I am testing out the load tester from shiny and I am having trouble recording a session. From this youtube video from Rstudio https://resources.rstudio.com/webinars/load-testing-shiny-alan-dipert , the instructor mentions grabbing the url of the deployed application. I have tried both the url from my server/browser application and the url from my deployed application on shinyapps io. I have also tried running it on Rstudio Cloud and I am redirected to a login which then shoots me to a 404 error. I have tried getting the URL from Mozzila, Microsoft Edge, and Chrome without luck.

```
library(shinyloadtest)
#server application
record_session("http://127.0.0.1:3793/") 
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(appUrl, handle = h) : 
  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3793: Connection refused

#deployed shiny app
record_session(" https://finance.shinyapps.io/PrivateApp/")#this is not the real url
Error in .subset2(public_bind_env, "initialize")(...) : 
  Recording shinyapps.io apps is not supported
```

I am looking to find the right url to add to record_session so I can begin load testing my application. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the package's [vigentte](https://rstudio.github.io/shinyloadtest/articles/limitations-of-shinyloadtest.html) and on the [GitHub thread](https://github.com/rstudio/shinyloadtest/pull/35) the author was clear that **you cannot benchmark against a Shiny app hosted on shinyapps.io**:

Under Deployment Limitations it says:

> **1. WebSockets are required**: On RStudio Connect and Shiny Server Pro, SockJS is used instead of plain WebSockets in order to support browsers and load balancers that don’t support WebSockets. Even though Shiny works in the absence of WebSocket support, shinyloadtest does not.
>
> **2. shinyapps.io unsupported**: Applications deployed on http://www.shinyapps.io/ can’t be recorded or load tested.

Instead, the documentation suggested that you should install the package *on your development machine*.

Otherwise, `shinyloadtest` works perfectly fine (tested on multiple versions of R 3.5 and above). The function `record_session()` takes the URL of the deployed application as an argument:

```
shinyloadtest::record_session('https://your-deployed-shinyapp.com/')
```

Taken from the documentation:

> Running the function will open a browser displaying the app. Once open, interact with the application as a normal user would and then close the browser. After closing the browser window or tab, a file will be created that contains a recording of the session. This recording, written to recording.log by default, will serve as the basis for the load test.

Comment: phantom I am a bit confused. If I do not have Rstudio Connect or Siny Server Pro, is there still a way for me to load test? Everything mentioned uses Rstudio Connect

Comment: You don't need Shiny Server Pro or RStudio Connect. As long as can deploy shiny app (typically on a Linux host) then you can use `shinyloadtest`. Shiny Server has an open source version, and you can get a free / basic plan from Azure VM to host it there